# How to use a partial layout with a collection? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, collections, partials

I am calling:

```
render @users, :layout => "homepage"
```

because I want to wrap the default partial for users (views/_user.html.erb) with a custom layout just for the homepage (views/users/_homepage.html.erb).

but, when I do this, I get the NoMethodError on the user.name method.

For some reason it seems like the user variable is not getting initialized properly inside the user partial.

It turns out after some test, the homepage partial is not even getting called, it is going straight to the user  partial ....

Comment: oh, and the spacer won't work because I need to WRAP the user partial with some layout code, not just put something in between each user.

Comment: Where are you calling this render statement from?

Comment: called from a homepage controller view, the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Sept. 2019, in Rails 6, this is how we are doing this:

```
<%= render partial: 'homepage_user_list_entry', collection: @users %>
```

With alias:

```
<%= render partial: 'homepage_user_list_entry', collection: @banned_users, as: :user %>
```

Hope this helps future searchers, and also me in the future.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the solution I wanted, I believe there may actually be a way to make this work using just a call to render, but this is what gave me the correct output:

```
@users.each do |user|
  render :partial => "users/user",
         :layout => "users/homepage",
         :locals => { :user => user }
end
```

Or is it that the :layout option only works when rendering a single resource and not a collection?

Comment: I was just looking for a way to do the same, and your way seems to be the only way to do it right now. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html for more info - if you check at the bottom, render_collection and render_partial are two completely different methods.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `:as => :user` to render a partial from a view:

`<%= render :collection => @users, :as => :user, :partial => 'users/user_short_form', %>`

Comment: After reading the docs the :as option tells Rails that the object you pass as an argument, in this example, @users, will be named whatever you set :as to, as a local variable in the partial.

I don't think this answers the original question, though, which is how to use both a layout and a collection when using the `render` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like

```
<%= render 'homepage', :collection => @users, :layout => 'homepage' %>
```

not sure about the :layout option, but you have to pass @users thro :collection

hope it helps!

Comment: I get: undefined local variable or method `user'

Comment: possibly, using the :as option suggested by robertg would work with this particular suggestion.